# What does mean this operator in a python code from Mask R-CNN framework

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to implement this code from Mask R-CNN framework but I don't understand what does mean this code:

```
# Compute VOC-Style mAP @ IoU=0.5
# Running on 10 images. Increase for better accuracy.
image_ids = np.random.choice(dataset_val.image_ids, 10)
APs = []
for image_id in image_ids:
    # Load image and ground truth data
    image, image_meta, gt_class_id, gt_bbox, gt_mask =\
        modellib.load_image_gt(dataset_val, inference_config,
                               image_id, use_mini_mask=False)
    molded_images = np.expand_dims(modellib.mold_image(image, inference_config), 0)
    # Run object detection
    results = model.detect([image], verbose=0)
    r = results[0]
    # Compute AP
    AP, precisions, recalls, overlaps =\
        utils.compute_ap(gt_bbox, gt_class_id, gt_mask,
                         r["rois"], r["class_ids"], r["scores"], r['masks'])
    APs.append(AP)
    
print("mAP: ", np.mean(APs))
```

Exactly I don't understand why matterport used it =\ here we can see:

```
image, image_meta, gt_class_id, gt_bbox, gt_mask =\
        modellib.load_image_gt(dataset_val, inference_config,
                               image_id, use_mini_mask=False)
```

If In run this code python says:

```
File "<ipython-input-32-2ea0c4541f94>", line 7
    image, image_meta, gt_class_id, gt_bbox, gt_mask =\ modellib.load_image_gt(dataset_val, inference_config, image_id)
                                                                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

If I remove this \ y got this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-5c299a0a0d9b> in <module>()
     11     r = results[0]
     12     #Compute AP
---> 13     AP, precisions, recalls, overlaps = utils.compute_ap(gt_bbox, gt_class_id, gt_mask, r["rois"], r["class_ids"], r["scores"], r['masks'])
     14     APs.append(AP)
     15 

2 frames
/content/MaskRCNN_Video/mrcnn/utils.py in compute_overlaps_masks(masks1, masks2)
    113 
    114     # intersections and union
--> 115     intersections = np.dot(masks1.T, masks2)
    116     union = area1[:, None] + area2[None, :] - intersections
    117     overlaps = intersections / union

<__array_function__ internals> in dot(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: shapes (3,262144) and (3136,2) not aligned: 262144 (dim 1) != 3136 (dim 0)
```

Original code image:

[image]

Apparently the original code works as we can see in the picture.
I will appreciate any suggestion to fix this error. thanks so much.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that backslash just indicates that you are going to continue on the next line. So it is setting those variables = to whatever is on the next line.

Comment: Thanks apparently is that..